# Where is ZCTA/CBSA relationship file for 2016?

Tags: geospatial, us-census

I am looking for the updated ZCTA to CBSA Relationship files. I can only find one for 2010, but there is a Tiger2016 ZCTA...where is the updated relationship file? Or is there another way to find this data?

http://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/maps-data/data/rel/zcta_cbsa_rel_10.txt

I am mapping the ZCTAs within a list of CBSAs and I have gaps caused by missing ZCTAs.

What am I missing here? [image]

Comment: could you use zip codes instead?  https://www.huduser.gov/portal/datasets/usps_crosswalk.html

Comment: I think @AnthonyDamico should write an answer based on his comment. I don't believe that Census updates the crosswalk files for annual TIGER updates between the big decennial version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Census Bureau does not update crosswalk files beyond the decennial remapping. Anthony Damico's suggestion of [using HUD's crosswalk files](https://www.huduser.gov/portal/datasets/usps_crosswalk.html), which are updated quarterly, is the best answer.

*(Marking this as a community-wiki answer since I don't intend to take credit, just want there to be an "answer" to this question.)*

Comment: how does one mark things as community wiki?

Comment: @Albert when editing your own answer there's a checkbox on the lower right that says 'community wiki'. You can see that right now below the edit memo *Your answer*

Comment: thanks. i feel like i should know all of this already...my bad.